# Error publishing data to topic

Tags: ros, gazebo, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I was working on a small python program to control a robot arm in Gazebo. My goal with this small program is to make the arm do an oscillating motion and I use /joint_group_pos_controller/command to publish the joint states.

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# license removed for brevity
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from std_msgs.msg import Float64MultiArray
#from trajectory_msgs import JointTrajectory

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/joint_group_pos_controller/command', Float64MultiArray, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('arm_move_control', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        hello_str = "hello world %s" % rospy.get_time()
        rospy.loginfo(hello_str)
        data = [0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.57, 0.0, -0.5]
        pub.publish(1,data)
        rospy.sleep(4)
        data = [0.0, -1.57, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.5]
        pub.publish(1,data)
        rospy.sleep(4)

    if rospy.is_shutdown():
        rospy.loginfo("---- SHUTTING DOWN ----")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

So when I run the code I get this error:

```
[INFO] [1631362769.809577, 0.000000]: hello world 0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hdani-ros/catkin_ws/src/ur_keyboard_teleop/scripts/ur_keyboard_teleop.py", line 28, in <module>
    talker()
  File "/home/hdani-ros/catkin_ws/src/ur_keyboard_teleop/scripts/ur_keyboard_teleop.py", line 17, in talker
    pub.publish(data)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 879, in publish
    data = args_kwds_to_message(self.data_class, args, kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 122, in args_kwds_to_message
    return data_class(*args)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/_Float64MultiArray.py", line 74, in __init__
    super(Float64MultiArray, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 344, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Invalid number of arguments, args should be %s' % str(self.__slots__) + ' args are' + str(args))
TypeError: Invalid number of arguments, args should be ['layout', 'data'] args are([0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.57, 0.0, -0.5],)
```

Can someone clarify as to what I need to change in order to send just the joint states?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386284/error-publishing-data-to-topic/) by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `pub.publish()` takes a single message, a `std_msgs/Float64MultiArrray` in this case.

```
$ rosmsg info std_msgs/Float64MultiArray
std_msgs/MultiArrayLayout layout
  std_msgs/MultiArrayDimension[] dim
    string label
    uint32 size
    uint32 stride
  uint32 data_offset
float64[] data
```

You need to create an instance of this message, then populate all the required fields before you pass it to publish(). Unless you can find documentation for some magic shortcut for a single-dimension array, you've got to fill in the msg accurately.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on 2021-09-12**:
Ok, so I changed the code to this:

```
movement_data = Float64MultiArray()

jointStates = [0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.57, 0.0, -0.5]
movement_data.data = [' ', 0, 0, 0, jointStates]
pub.publish(movement_data)
rospy.sleep(4)
```

It now publishes and runs without errors, but the robot arm in gazebo doesn't move at all.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-12**:
That does not look like a valid description of a 1-dimensional array to me, but I don't know what the receiving side is looking for.

**Comment by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on 2021-09-12**:
This is what the message looks like when I publish it from the terminal (which is the method that works):

```
rostopic pub /joint_group_position_controller/command std_msgs/Float64MultiArray "layout:
    dim:
    - label: ' '
      size: 0
      stride: 0
    data_offset: 0
data: [0.0, -1.57, 0.0, -1.57, 0.0, 0.0]"
```